# Laravel - Restrict only upto 2 API calls

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

I am connecting my app to an API which allows only 2 simultaneous API calls.

How can I restrict this from my app? If more than 2 concurrent API request is generated through my app, I want to restrict this.

I can do this by setting a flag in table or so, but what I would to know is, Is there a smarter laravel way of doing this?

Laravel verion 5.4.

Comment: Do you want 2 concurrent users or 2 concurrent API requests? Both are too different.

Comment: 2 concurrent requests. I have edited the quesiton

Comment: @Dilani read this https://github.com/imliam/laravel-throttle-simultaneous-requests

Comment: My requirement is user independent. Many users may access the app at the same time, but only 2 API calls are allowed over all

Answer (score 0):

You need to share number of active API calls across multiple processes.

You can use shared memory in combination with semaphores for this purpose.

You have several options to work with shared memory i.e.: shmop, shm, apc

And you can use sem_acquire / sem_release to restrict simultaneous access to the shared memory.

So you can make couple of functions to queue API calls:

```
function aquire_permission_for_api_call(){
    $sem = sem_get("api_call_manager");
    $ok=false;
    do {
        sem_aquire($sem);
        $active_calls_storage = shm_attach("api_call_manager_storage");
        $number_of_active_calls = shm_get_var($active_calls_storage,0);
        if($number_of_active_calls<2){
            $number_of_active_calls++;
            $ok=true;
            shm_put_var($active_calls_storage,0, number_of_active_calls);
        }
        sem_release($sem);
    }while(!$ok);

}

function report_completion_of_api_call(){
    $sem = sem_get("api_call_manager");
    sem_aquire($sem);
    $active_calls_storage = shm_attach("api_call_manager_storage");
    $number_of_active_calls = shm_get_var($active_calls_storage,0);
    $number_of_active_calls-;
    shm_put_var($active_calls_storage,0, number_of_active_calls);
    sem_release($sem);
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
aquire_permission_for_api_call();
$response = $client->make_api_call();
report_completion_of_api_call();
```

PS: I did not test this code. I hope you get an idea.